# Timer in every page

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I want the timer to be displayed in all my activities. So I have written a Countdown timer method in MainActivity and trying to call them from other classes. Which is not working. It works fine in MainActivity but crashes when called from another class. Looks like I have not called the method right.

```
MainActivity : // Timer starts and works fine in this page

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView text;
    Button button,button1;
    CountDownTimer counterTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timerText);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startbutton);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.newPagebutton);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    public void SetTimer(){
         counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                text.setText(" "+String.format(" %d min %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)- TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                text.setText(" done !!!");

            }
        };
        counterTimer.start();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.startbutton :
                SetTimer();
                counterTimer.start();
                break;
            case R.id.newPagebutton :
                Intent in = new Intent(this,NewPage.class);
                startActivity(in);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

New Page : // Crashes when tried to start timer in this page

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class NewPage extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button button3;
    TextView text;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_page);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_page, menu);
        Intent in = getIntent();
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2Text);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start2button);
        button3.setOnClickListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2Text);
        MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
        mainActivity.SetTimer();
        mainActivity.counterTimer.start();

    }
```

Logcat :

```
09-10 14:23:46.270  26657-26657/com.example.timer1 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.timer1, PID: 26657
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
            at com.example.timer1.MainActivity$1.onTick(MainActivity.java:44)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:133)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is the TextView throwing the nullpointer:

> 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference

The only place where you called `setText()` is in this method:

```
public void SetTimer(){
     counterTimer = new CountDownTimer(60000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText(" "+String.format(" %d min %d sec", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)- TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished))));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            text.setText(" done !!!");

        }
    };
    counterTimer.start();

}
```

So `TextView text;` could be the cause, you should set it in in `onCreate()` rather than `onCreateOptionsMenu` even if it supposed to get called after onCreate

Comment: & @ Flink : I did as you said, Defined Text view in onCreate and deleted in all other places also made protected Text view and changed the id for newpage Textview same as Mainactivity one, but still same problem it works for Mainpage but the moment I try in new page it says : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the "text" TextView in your onCreate method, but this is not (the only) problem, the problem is that you have to define the text TextView as protected on your MainActivity and NOT redefine it in the child classes, otherwise you will override the base object defining a new one with the same name.

Just change:

```
TextView text -> protected TextView
```

In MainActivity. While delete every "TextView text" definition in others child activity. You should let the line:

```
text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer2Text);
```

In the children, since the id may differ (as in the case you showed). If the id stays the same, you can delete this line too.